# Range Function That Prints Even Numbers From 100 To 200 Inclusive

Tags: python, for-loop

I have to create a range function so that the code prints the even numbers between 100 and 200 inclusive.

The solution I tried is

```
num = 100
for x in range(num % 2, 200):
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

range(start,end,step)

```
list(range(100,200,2))
```

Comment: I would recommend to change it to ```list(range(100,201,2))``` to make it 100 and 200 inclusive.